# should I use a redirect to track conversion? and how do I make a PHP countdown?

Tags: javascript, php

I have visitors entering a certain PHP landing page, which has a link to an external website.

I want to track whether each visitor clicked that link, and receive additional info such as what was the HTTP referrer of it, entry time, clicking time, visit duration, browser etc.

One option that covers only tracking the HTTP referrer (actually, it would show me the "clean" search term that the visitor used to get to my website) is to use a piece of JavaScript code, which was generated by an automatic tool that my traffic source offers.

Since I'm sending the visitors to an external website, I suppose that the only way to have such a tracking, would be to send first anyone who clicks on the link, to an auto redirect page on my site that would contain this code.

Now, Assuming all my assumptions are correct (if not, please advise):

1) What other options do I have, besides using this automatic generated code?

2) Should such a redirect page be a PHP page?

3) In such a PHP page, I've read that it would be best to use:

```
    header('Refresh: 3;url=http://www.external-page.com');
```

4) I assume 3 seconds are enough for the JavaScript code to fully work, Is there a way to display the visitor a dynamic countdown message?

5) I want the external website to open in a new browser window, is there a way with PHP to open such a window that would not contain any toolbars, and to have this window open up at a certain size (not the whole screen like with a "_blank" target)? if not, how do I do this with Javascript? does it involove a plugin?

6) What If I have to transform multiple landing pages to work in this way? should I manually create an individual redirect page for each landing page, or is there a way to make a template, that would receive the link input from the original page? maybe sending the user to a

```
   redirect.php?link=http://link1.com
```

and then "GET" the link and echo it in the url, but It doesn't seem to be clean enough, I prefer that the user would not see such a messy destination url when he points on the link.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you could also send an asynchronous ajax request on the click and redirect it on success

Answer (score 0):

Just add a click event listener on your links and redirect directly to the remote site on success (assuming you are using jquery) :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').on('click', function(){
        var href = $(this).attr('href');

        // Send a transparent POST request to your server
        $.post(
            '/tracking-url', 
            {
                url: href // you will have access to $_POST['url'] containing your href attribute value
            },
            function(response) {
                // On success event 
                // If everything is ok (server-side), just redirect the user to the site
                window.location = href;
            }
        ).fail(function() {
            // something unexpected occured
            alert("error");
        });

        return false; // prevents the default event behaviour
    });
});
```

And leave the link as it was :

```
<a href="http://link1.com">Go to link1</a>
```

See **[jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)**
You can also use **[jQuery.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)** to access a `$_GET[]` value.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure which one of my questions does this solve?
 is it possible to implement the javascript tracking with this method?

Comment: It's hard to tell without knowing what your generated javascript code is. But here you can at least ask for your server and make anything you want before redirecting your user.